# Development of Logic: Intuitive use vs what took so long to formalize?

Tags: mathematical-logic

I was encouraged in MathOverflow to ask this question here - so here it goes: As I am reading Frege and Boole, I am struck by that there doesn't seem to be a great alternative to Aristotle's Logic until that time, and the development by Boole and Frege are correctly hailed as a revolution in the development the subject.

However, mathematicians have clearly been using first-order (& propositional) logic correctly in their proofs well before then, and indeed, humans - including small children! use simple forms of first order logic, and writers when constructing arguments for their books of political philosophy or whatever also employ non-Aristotelian logic freely.

So what took so long for Frege and Boole / humans to overthrow old syllogistic logic? "It's obvious in hindsight"'s not the answer I am looking for (see above).

Comment: "mathematicians have clearly been using first-order (& propositional) logic correctly in their proofs " Not in the modern sense.

Comment: See [Leibniz’s Influence on 19th Century Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-logic-influence/). The "new wave" of modern logic started after the development of modern algebraic symbolism in the 17th Century.

Comment: Correct "propositional argument" was obviously used by Aristotle as well as by [Ancient logicians](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ancient/). The issue is that only Aristotle developed a "complete system" very similar to the modern ones, and his approach was *formal* in the modern sense (but obviously without the use of modern "algebra like" symbols).

Comment: There has been a propositional alternative to Aristotle's syllogistic since ancient times [developed by Stoics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ancient/#Sto). For historical reasons, their texts did not survive, unlike Aristotle's, and their work was only reconstructed after its reinvention in 19th century. As for mathematicians, they have not been "clearly" using first-order logic, they had semantic alternatives to achieve their ends. For a classical study in the case of Euclid see [Manders, Euclidean Diagram](https://academic.oup.com/book/2780/chapter-abstract/143290265).